# offset / while loop problem - using google apps script to download mailchimp 'members' data from list

Tags: google-apps-script, while-loop, offset, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Hey I'm trying to write a google apps script that gets all [Mailchimp email addresses](https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/lists/) and statuses into a google sheet.  However, it stops after the first 1,000 and I can't figure out the off-set / get_all that I need to make this work.

```
function mailchimpMembers() {

  // URL and params for the Mailchimp API
  var root = 'https://us19.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/';
  var endpoint = 'lists/' + LIST_ID + '/members?offset=0&count=10000';

  var params = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'apikey ' + API_KEY
    }
  };

  try {
    // call the Mailchimp API

    var keep_going = true;
    var offset = 0;
    var memberList = new Array();
    memberList.push(["email","status"]);


     while(keep_going) {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(root+endpoint+offset, params);
        var data = response.getContentText();
        var json = JSON.parse(data);
      keep_going = json["get_all"];
      offset = json.offset;
      var listGrowth = json['members'];
      listGrowth.forEach(function(el) {
      memberList.push([el.email_address, el.status]);
    });
    Logger.log(memberList);
    };

  writeResults("list",memberList);
  }
  catch (error) {

    Logger.log(error);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results from this API are paginated. See the *Pagination* section in MailChimp's [Getting Started](https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#Parameters) guide. This type of pagination is fairly typical for these types of APIs.

With each GET request, you'll need to set `count` for the number of results per page. (I see you've already done this, but I think you have a typo. You have '10000' in your code instead of '1000'.)

You'll also need to set `offset` to start the results of each page after the last result of the previous page. So if your `count` is 1000, you'll need to increment the offset by a thousand each time:

```
offset = offset + 1000
```

Finally, to set your `keep_going` boolean, you'll need to check if the next offset exceeds the total number of results. This particular endpoint returns a `total_items` property, which you can use for this comparison:

```
keep_going = offset > total_items
```

Make sure you're doing this comparison *after* you've updated the offset (opposite to what is currently in your code). Otherwise, you'll be checking the offset for the request you just made.

P.S. You'll need to re-write your original `endpoint` definition to not hard-code a value for the offset, since you'll need to re-write this value in your while-loop. I recommend:

```
var endpoint = 'lists/' + LIST_ID + '/members?count=10000&offset=';
```

Comment: This is great!  Thanks!